# Python memory error when memory is available

Tags: python, windows, memory, out-of-memory

I have a Python program that reads lines of files and analyzes them. The program intentionally reads many lines into the RAM.

The program started getting MemoryError while appending a line (as str) to list. When I check in the task manager (the program runs on Windows 10), I see that the memory of the program is on 1635MB (stable) and the total memory use of the machine is below 50%.

I read that Python does not limit the memory, so what could be the reason?

Technical details:

I use Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10, 64-bit 16GB RAM machine. I run the program from the PowerShell terminal and not through the IDE.

Comment: How big are the files you are reading? And how long does the list get when this happens?

Comment: Check if you aren't using 32-bit installation of Python.

Comment: It's not easy to match the memory error with the total RAM (with out without swap).  There are lots of behind the scene details that affect memory use and limits.  Just accept that fact that with large tasks you will hit a memory error, sooner or later.

Comment: _while appending a line (as str) to list_ I’m curious to see your code, can you post it?

Answer (score 3):

> I see that the memory of the program is on 1635MB

Windows EXEs compiled as 32-bit have, by default, a 2GB memory limit even when on 64-bit OS SKUs where plenty more memory is available.  You're at 1.6 GB, so you're probably bumping up against this limit.

Make sure you are running the 64-bit version of Python.exe. Python.org's download page defaults to 32-bit for unknown reasons.  But if you browse to the bottom of [their download page for a given release](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/), you can find the x86-64 version for 64-bit architecture.